# Find a power series representation for $\frac{1}{2+x}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

> Find a power series representation for $\frac{1}{2+x}$

The question did not specify a real number $c$ and an expansion on the form

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n(x-c)^n.$$

I did this problem as follows, but I seem to be off by a factor of $1/3$.

$$\frac{1}{2+x} = \frac{1}{1+(x+1)}=\frac{1}{1-[-(x+1)]}.$$

Putting this into the geometric form of:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a}{1-r},$$ I get $a=1$ and $r=-(x-1).$ So, this could be written as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(-1)(x-1)]^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(x-1)^n.$$

Wolfram's widget gets the following:

$$\frac{1}{2+x}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1+x)^n(-1)^n3^{-1-n}\quad \text{for}|-1+x|\lt3$$

which looks like my answer except for the $3^\left(-1-n\right)$ term.

Can you assist me in finding my error?  I don's see where the $1/3$ term gets introduced.

Comment: You did not say what the “center of expansion” should be: you seem to have sought powers of $x+1$, making the center $x=-1$; or, later in your work, powers of $x-1$, making the center $x=1$. My immediate preference would have been powers of $x$, making the center zero. You pays your money and takes your choice, in each case getting a different radius of convergence. The important thing is that your domain of convergence will never include $x=-2$.

Comment: $$2+x=3+(x-1),$$ no ?

Comment: @hm2020  The user originally tagged this question with [tag:calculus] and [tag:power-series].  This helps to understand what level of answer the user is expecting.  Adding the tags [tag:functions] and [tag:real-analysis] changes the focus of the question, and potentially leads users to give answers at the wrong level.

Comment: @XanderHenderson - My motivation for the added tags was that this question has "general interest"  - others (with varying background and level) may find this post and learn someting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}=\frac{1}{3+(x-1)}=\frac{1}{3}~~\frac{1}{[1+(x-1)/3]}$$
Use IGP
$$\implies f(x)=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k [(x-1)/3] ^k, ~if~ |x-1|<3. $$

Comment: I don't know what IGP is.  Does this mean that my solution is incorrect?  I don't see a math error in my solution.

Comment: @user163862 see my answer to see where you missed a sign

Comment: can't I write $2+x$ as $1-[-(x+1)]$???

Comment: Actually - I made a typo in my original question.  but I didn't carry the typo into the answer.

Comment: Yes you can, but $-(x+1)\ne-x+1$

Comment: Yes, that is where my typo was.  But notice I didn't carry the typo into my $r$ value.  It was just a typo.  My work has $r=-(x+1)$ so my $r$ value is $-(x+1)$.  I still don't get a factor of 1/3

Comment: I do see my error in $-1$

Comment: @user163862 in your case  $r=-(x+1)$ (notice your mistake) and you will get a series in $-(x+1)$ which will be valid for $|x+1|<1$ which is also valid but it is not a power series in $(x-1)$ as in my answer and in Mathematica,

Comment: Yes, I absolutely see that.  I completely understand.  But, since the original question didn't ask for any c value, isn't my answer still correct?

Comment: (+1) You got the largest circle of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another answer: For this rational function it is possible to give an elementary construction of a powerseries and an "equality"

$$ \frac{1}{2+x}=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n(x-a)^n$$

for any $a\neq -2$:

$$\frac{1}{2+x}=\frac{1}{2(1-(-x/2))} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-\frac{x}{2})^n=$$

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}.$$

I used

$$\frac{1}{1-t}=\sum_{n\geq 0} t^n$$

with $t:=-\frac{x}{2}$.

We can generalize as follows (let $a\neq -2$):

$$ \frac{1}{2+x}=\frac{1}{2+a-(-(x-a))} =$$

$$ \frac{1}{2+a}\frac{1}{1-(-(\frac{x-a}{2+a}))}=$$

(here we let $t:=\frac{x-a}{2+a}$)

$$ \frac{1}{2+a}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-(\frac{x-a}{2+a}))^n.$$

We get a power series

$$\frac{1}{2+x}= \frac{1}{2+a}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n(\frac{x-a}{2+a})^n.$$

With $a:=1$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2+x}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^n(\frac{x-1}{3})^n.$$

When I write $=$ in the above equation this means for all $x$ where the powerseries converge. You should be able to calculate this radius of convergence yourself.

In general: If $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is a rational function over the reals, there is a product decomposition

$$P1.\text{  }g(x)=\prod_{i} (x-c_i)^{l_i}\prod_j p_j(x)^{k_j}$$

where $c_i$ are real numbers and $p_j(x)=b_j^2+(x-a_j)^2$ where $a_j,b_j\neq 0$ are real numbers. For a rational function on the form $\frac{1}{p_j(x)}$
you get a similar calculation:

$$ \frac{1}{p_j(x)}=\frac{1}{b_j^2+(x-a_j)^2}=$$

$$\frac{1}{p_j(x)}"="\frac{1}{b_j^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n(\frac{x-a_j}{b_j})^{2n} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{b_j^{2(n+1)}}(x-a_j)^{2n}.$$

Hence you can "in principle" construct an explicit formal power series expansion for any rational function $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ using the geometric series and partial fraction decomposition of the product in P1.

Comment: (+1) This is not the same origin. Call $D$ the circle of convergence. You get  $|x|/2<1\Longleftrightarrow |x|<2$ i.e. $D\cap \mathbb{R}=]-2,2[$. Z Ahmed answer gives $D\cap \mathbb{R}=]-2,4[$.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion comes from the fact that your answer is wrong. See the answer from Z Ahmed for a correct solution. In your solution you somehow transformed $x+1$ into $-x+1$. This happened when you wrote $r$.

**Note** that the different answers write a series around different points:

- yours is around $-1$, with small $x+1$
- the given answer, and the one from ZA is around $1$, with small $x-1$
- hm2020 expands around $0$, with small $x$

Comment: I see now that I made a typo in my work in the original question.  The $r$ should be $-(x+1)$.  This still doesn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: If you fix your calculations it will give you an answer that is different, but not less correct. Multiple series can converge to the same function